# How to print GoogleV3 location in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, geopy

I have thousands of address in my dataframe, I was cry paste for one-by-one longitude and latitude in spreadsheet, but I want to automate this in thousands of address.
Here's my previous code

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key= "Code")
location = geolocator.geocode("JL.Balitung III")
print((location.latitude, location.longitude))
```

This is the output

```
(-6.232012999999999, 106.8087392)
```

Here's my data

```
id  Address 
1   JL.Balitung III
2   Jalan Balitung III
3   Jl Balitung III
```

Here's what I want

```
id  Address                  Latitude               Longitude        
1   JL.Balitung III          -6.232012999999999     106.8087392
2   Jalan Erlangga III       -6.2336678             106.8086881
3   Jalan Senopati           -6.2302063             106.8066563
```

Comment: I was just want to make the answerer easier

Comment: Yes, without it I cannot test it, so thank you. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom function and assign to new columns:

```
from geopy.geocoders import GoogleV3
geolocator = GoogleV3(api_key= "code")

def f(x):
    location = geolocator.geocode(x)
    return pd.Series((location.latitude, location.longitude))

df[['Latitude','Longitude']] = df['Address'].apply(f)
print (df)
   id             Address  Latitude   Longitude
0   1     JL.Balitung III -6.232013  106.808739
1   2  Jalan Erlangga III -6.233668  106.808688
2   3      Jalan Senopati -6.230206  106.806656
```